# React doesn't update when CSS File is changed

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles, webpack-dev-server

So I'm new to React.
I want to style a simple text and found out how to use styles, but when I want to change something in the CSS I have to restart my React App which always takes 3 Minutes.

I use `npm start` to start the React server that was created with create-react-app.

How can I let React update when the CSS file is changed?

I have an index.js that looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from  './Frontend/App.js';
import './Frontend/style/main.css';

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And an App.js that looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './style/main.css';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        var pageHeading = (
            <h1 className="pageHeading">bosleeir.it</h1>);
        return pageHeading;
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: are you using custom Webpack configuration?

Comment: I am using the standard server provided by create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you need to import your CSS in your component. I wouldn't recommend to do it on index.js

I'm assuming your folder structure is:

[image]

which could lead me that:

1. You're using an older version of React
2. You have modified the structure of your files

So double-check if the path are configured correctly.